# Forcibly changing the address of an array(where array name is pointing) by call by address. error exists, but it seems working though..?

Tags: c

I vaguely know that array name may seem like pointer type, but it is not.

(I understood that array just decays to pointer, is not the pointer itself. Please let me know if my understanding is wrong)

So I've thought that passing &arrayname1 and &arrayname2 to below function can't be compiled.

```
void    swap(char **a, char **b)
{
        char *temp;
        temp = *a;
        *a = *b;
        *b = temp;
}
```

But when I compile a test.c file below, it gives me warnings but the function works.

```
int     main()
{
        char a[] = "12";
        char b[] = "ab";


        swap(&a, &b);
        // char c[] = "asdb";
        printf("%s %s\n", a ,b);

        return (0);
}
```

and the outcome was like below,

```
ab 12
*** stack smashing detected ***: terminated
Aborted
```

Next, I inserted a meaningless statement to check if "stack smashing detected" message could be disappeared. and the message disappeared.

```
int     main()
{
        char a[] = "12";
        char b[] = "ab";


        swap(&a, &b);
        char c[] = "asdb";
        printf("%s %s\n", a ,b);

        return (0);
}
```

So my questions are..

1. Could changing the address which array name is pointing possible?
2. When does "stack smashing detected" message appears, and what does that mean? (I've googled that, but couldn't find relationship between the message and the codes)
3. Why the second outcome does not come with the "stack smashing detected"?

(Please understand if there is any rude expression because I am not good at English.)

Comment: Your understanding of arrays is roughly correct. The issue is that you can’t change the address of objects in memory.

Comment: The content of a pointer is an address, but the content of your arrays are chars which is what you are swapping.  This would be clear with longer strings.

Answer (score 2):

If you invoke your compiler in standard-conforming mode then it must print a diagnostic message for this incorrect code.

Many compilers go on and compile incorrect code anyway unless you are quite forcible to tell them not to do so.

Check your compiler documentation for this. In GCC you use switch `-pedantic` or `-pedantic-errors` along with an ISO conformance mode such as `-std=c11` .

---

It's not possible to change the address of any object that already exists, arrays are no exception. The code contains a constraint violation (as you point out - incompatible type of function argument) and therefore is not a valid C program , so the compiler is not bound to enforce the rules that apply to valid programs. Hence you can get all sorts of unexpected behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

1. No. Where to place arrays (not dynamically allocated) is determined at compile time and cannot be changed at run time.
2. The message appears when stack smashing is detected. In this case `swap` write 4-byte or 8-byte (depending on the platform, also maybe other size) value to the passed pointers, but the passed pointers are actually pointing at 3-byte arrays, so writing to out-of-bounds is happened and *undefined behavior* is invoked.
3. Maybe the addition of `c` put `a` and `b` far enough from important data (the return address, for example) and prevented it from detection of broken data.